# Is the price of a binary call not monotonous with vol for OTM

Tags: options, volatility, binary

Is this true and how would you prove it

Comment: Did you mean "monotonic"?

Answer (score 2):

The OTM binary is not increasing with volatility. Simply plot the price as a function of implied volatility. eg take

S = 0.99
K = 1 
r=0
T =1

and $\sigma$ vary upwards in steps of 0.01 starting at 0. It peaks around 0.04.

Differentiating $d_2$ with respect to $\sigma$ makes this behaviour obvious.